# Issue with PHP array where keys are large integers

Tags: php, arrays, timestamp

What i'm tring to do here is basically start from `$stats` and get an array `$counts` containing four arrays, where each array is a pair: **key is a timestamp in milliseconds** while values are counts. Im using PHP Version 5.3.14 on Windows 7 x64.

Question is: why i'm getting negatives array keys values and how can avoid this? See `var_dump()` below:

```
$stats = array();
$stats[] = array(
    'subtype' => 'small_text_message_user',
    'count'   => '6',
    'date'    => '2012-06-03'
);

$stats[] = array(
    'subtype' => 'small_text_message_auto',
    'count'   => '3',
    'date'    => '2012-07-03',
);

$stats = array(
    'subtype' => 'newsletter_auto',
    'count' => '11',
    'date' => '2012-07-16',
);

$counts = array();
$counts['small_text_message_user'] = array();
$counts['small_text_message_auto'] = array();
$counts['newsletter_user']         = array();
$counts['newsletter_auto']         = array();

foreach($data as $stat) :
    $millisecs = 1000 * strtotime($stat['date']);
    $count     = intval($stat['count']);
    $counts[$stat['subtype']][$millisecs] = $count;
    var_dump($millisecs, $count);
endforeach;

var_dump($counts);
```

And result is wrong:

```
float 1338674400000

int 6

float 1341266400000

int 3

float 1342389600000

int 11

array (size=4)
  'small_text_message_user' => 
    array (size=1)
      -1355396352 => int 6
  'small_text_message_auto' => 
    array (size=1)
      1236603648 => int 3
  'newsletter_user' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'newsletter_auto' => 
    array (size=1)
      -1935163648 => int 11
```

An example (which works, actually) is a short piece of code where i'm generating a "dummy" array:

```
public function createTimestampRangeFromDates(\DateTime $from,
    \DateTime $to = null)
{
    $start = strtotime($from->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
    $limit = strtotime(sprintf('%s 00:00:00', $to ? $to->format('Y-m-d')
        : date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00'));

    return range($start, $limit, 86400);
}

// Test
$start = new \DateTime('2012-06-27');
$end   = new \DateTime('2012-07-07'); // 10 days

$timestamps = createTimestampRangeFromDates($start, $end);
$millisecs  = array_combine($timestamps, array_fill(0, count($timestamps), 0));

var_dump($millisecs);
```

This **works fine and i get large integers** as keys:

```
array (size=11)
  '1340748000000' => int 0
  '1340834400000' => int 0
  '1340920800000' => int 0
  '1341007200000' => int 0
  '1341093600000' => int 0
  '1341180000000' => int 0
  '1341266400000' => int 0
  '1341352800000' => int 0
  '1341439200000' => int 0
  '1341525600000' => int 0
  '1341612000000' => int 0
```

Oh, if this matters, purpose of this code is to do something like:

```
$values = array_merge($millisecs, $counts['newsletter_auto']);
```

That is overriding the dummy array with real values.

## Update small test case as suggested by @hakre

```
$result1 = array();
$result2 = array();
$test    = array('2012-06-03', '2012-07-03', '2012-07-16');

foreach($test as $date) :
    $result1[1000 * strtotime($date)] = 0;
    $result2[] = 1000 * strtotime($date);
endforeach;

var_dump($result1); // Not working
var_dump($result2); // Works
```

Result shows negative keys for `$result1`. Issue is only with keys, not for values (as value is converted to `float`):

```
array (size=3)
  -1355396352 => int 0
  1236603648 => int 0
  -1935163648 => int 0

array (size=3)
  0 => float 1338674400000
  1 => float 1341266400000
  2 => float 1342389600000
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using and are you running 64-bit PHP on a 64-bit platform?

Comment: What do you get from `echo PHP_INT_MAX;`? Looks like an integer overflow. If strings as keys are okay for you then give `...[strval(1000 * strtotime($stat['date']))]...` a try.

Comment: If it is a int overflow then look into `bcmath` http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php Replace the calculation with `bcmul(1000, strtotime($stat['date']))`

Comment: Please tell the exact PHP version you're using and the operating system you expeŕience this on. Also, please isolate the specific values that are generating the negative keys so that your issue can be reproduced better. Additionally if you use `var_dump` there is information about the datatypes used (e.g. int, float and string), too.

Comment: @hakre PHP Version 5.3.14 on Windows 7 x64. PHP_INT_MAX is 2147483647. See my edits for real values.

Comment: @Niko thanks for the tip about strval, i'll use it if can't solve this.

Comment: There still is this immensive overhead of code and values which hides the source of your problem: What is wrong exactly? Why is that wrong? What is your issue? Please make a small test-case with only some lines of code and the minimum data needed.

Comment: @hakre i updated my question. The wrong happens when large values are used as keys. Did you find something on PHP documentation that states a max length for array keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP converts nummeric (so, float or integer) array indexes to integer:

```
ckruse@lin ~ $ php -r 'var_dump(array(1.2 => "a"));'
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```

So if you have a very large array index, it will get converted to float by PHP when calculated and then back to integer when used as an index. This means that you get an integer overflow with to large indexes.

A solution can be to use string indexes:

```
ckruse@lin ~ $ php -r 'var_dump(array(((string)1.2) => "a"));'
array(1) {
  ["1.2"]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```

Edit: Manual on http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php says:

Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.

Comment: I posted my answer like yours at the same time. Anyway, i can't find any reference about this conversion for array keys.

Comment: @Gremo On http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php: Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.

Answer (score 1):

> Did you find something on PHP documentation that states a max length for array keys?

The PHP Manual defines it the following: *"A key may be either an integer or a string."* ([Source](http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php))

As every data-type, integers as well are limited. That is common in computing. Depending on how integers are being handled by the software or the underlying processor, they can either flip, floor or top.

In your case it goes over to the smallest negative number when the boundary is crossed. I call that *flip* others might call it *overflow*  or *wrap-around*.

You can find out about the boundaries with `PHP_INI_Min` and `PHP_INI_MAX`.

Take care for string keys, there is also a limit, it normally can not become greater than 2GB. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the part about integer overflow on the php documentation. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow

> "If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead."

Comment: This is not exactly what happens. My keys are converted to float in the first place; then keys are converted back to integers causing the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a little research shows that **floats as array keys are truncated to integer**. So my large floats truncated to integers results in an overflow. Still looking for an official documentation link.

See this (closed) bug [Array keys converted from float to integer](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32671) and this [article](http://www.michikono.com/2007/01/04/php-array-keys-and-floats/) and this [pull request](https://github.com/yetzt/boxing/pull/3).

**EDIT**: found on [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any
> type.
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> Floats are also cast to
> integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g.
> the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.